# Read stream detect file changes (continue after file end)

Tags: node.js, file, stream, readline, watch

I have trouble with a very simple task.

When i write to a file i want a read stream to be able to detect the newly written data to that file.

```js
const fs = require("fs");


const read = fs.createReadStream("./file.txt", {
    autoClose: false,
    emitClose: false
});


read.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log("Data", data);
});

read.on("close", () => {
    console.log("read closed");
})


setInterval(() => {
    fs.appendFile("./file.txt", String(Date.now()), (err) => {
        console.log(err || "written")
    });
}, 1000);
```

Im able to read the initial content of the file, but not anything that has written to it via `fs.appendFile`. Later then i want to use the read stream with the "readline" module and detect new added lines.

What would be the correct way to have a continuous read stream?

One possible solution could be to work with `fs.watch`, but how there only get the newly added data? (And use that as stream for the `readline` module?)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a mix out of `fs.watch` & `fs.read`:

```
    read() { }
});

fs.open("file.txt", (err, fd) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {

        let position = 0;

        // initial read
        // set offset bytes
        fs.read(fd, {
            position
        }, (err, bytesRead, buffer) => {
            if (err) {

                console.erro(err);
                process.exit(1);

            } else {

                position += bytesRead;
                readable.push(buffer.slice(0, bytesRead));

                console.log("Read, offset: INITIAL READ!", position);

            }
        });

        // listen for file changes
        // push to readable stream 
        // add readed bytes to offset
        fs.watch("file.txt", (event) => {
            if (event === "change") {

                fs.read(fd, {
                    position
                }, (err, bytesRead, buffer) => {
                    if (err) {

                        console.erro(err);
                        process.exit(1);

                    } else {

                        position += bytesRead;
                        readable.push(buffer.slice(0, bytesRead));

                        console.log("Read, offset:", position, bytesRead);

                    }
                });

            }
        })

    }
});
```

The readable stream can i then use for the `readline` interface.

If some one has a better solution, let me know.